# Как собрать статистику с сайта (не моего)?

Tags: парсер

Возник такой вопрос.

Вот есть сайт (будет называть его просто  сайт). При заходе на него он нам выдаёт какую - то информацию. Каждую  минуту эта  информация меняется. И мне нужно каким - то образом научиться собирать эту информацию с помощью компьютера.

Есть способы это сделать?

Answer (score 1):

Ну напишите standalone парсер, который будет запускаться с указанной вами частотой (программно или каким-нибудь scheduler'ом).